# This is my code to print the jtable on frame

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I added MouseListener to select a particular row from table,the content of row is getting printed on console but I want to print this content on new frame what should I do for this.
I attached my code along with the screenshot of the table.
thanks for help.

This is my code.

```
    final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
    cp.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(cp);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
         if(e.getClickCount()==1){
            JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
        System.out.println(target);
            int row = target.getSelectedRow();
        System.out.println(row);
        Object [] rowData = new Object[table.getColumnCount()];
        Object [] colData = new Object[table.getRowCount()];
        for(int j = 0;j < table.getRowCount();j++)
            for(int i = 0;i < table.getColumnCount();i++)
            {
               rowData[i] = table.getValueAt(j, i);
               System.out.println(rowData[i]);
             }
          }
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: use addactionlistener

Comment: How do you want it displayed?

Comment: The other question is why? You've got the data displayed in the table already? You're not expanding on it in any way...

Comment: You are right...Actually I want to display the selected data on the next frame.
Could you please help me with that. I tried a lot but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

When you output the result (`System.out.println(rowData[i]);`) just create a new JFrame and place the text you want to output here :

```
...
JFrame secondFrame = new JFrame();
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
for(int j = 0;j < table.getRowCount();j++){
    for(int i = 0;i < table.getColumnCount();i++){
           rowData[i] = table.getValueAt(j, i);
           JLabel label = new JLabel(rowData[i]);
           myPanel.add(label);
    }
}
secondFrame.add(myPanel);
secondFrame.setVisible(true);
....
```

Comment: I tried this but its printing each column on new frame. could you please tell me how to print one complete row on a new frame

Comment: I updated the code. The main idea is to create a new `JLabel` for each data you want to output, and display all this `JLabel` in one simple `JFrame`. I didn't try to compile this code, maybe you'll have few fix to make, but the main idea is here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you make a graphical interface with swing, you can't use System.out.print.
You need to set every row in a Label and print it out that way. If it is a Label then you can select it with your mouse

Answer (score 0):

In the Mouse Listener method, Call the new JFrame, 
in that JFrame , put the Contents of selected Row to Constructor Parameters.

JFrame newframe=new JFrame("Selected Contents);

Comment: Could you please me how to select one complete row into a label and print that on new frame.
I tried but its printing each column on new frame.
I want to displayed all the attributes on new column.

Comment: you have to use for loop on selected row cells. and append each cell value in string variable, then pass the variable to new JFrame form